# How to use orderby on meta_value when using Pods custom database table storage

Tags: loop, sql, order, pre-get-posts, pods-framework

I'm struggling to understand how I can use `pre_get_post` when the post's metadata is not stored in the wp_postmeta table. I use Pods (https://pods.io) to create custom post types with custom fields, stored using the plugins *Table Storage* option.

My desired outcome is to use `orderby` on the `meta_value` stored in the custom `xyz_custom_table` table.

The following `xyz_order_post_by_meta` function is how I would do this with posts that store metadata in the wp_postmeta table. But this will not work with custom database tables.

```
function xyz_order_post_by_meta($query)
{
  if (
    $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive("xyz_cpt")
  ) {
    $query->set("meta_key", "xyz_custom_meta");
    $query->set("orderby", "meta_value");
    $query->set("order", "ASC");
  }
}
add_action("pre_get_posts", "xyz_order_post_by_meta", 9999);
```

Am I right in thinking I need to run a custom SQL query to get the value for `meta_value` to include in the above? If so, how would I write this? I've tried the following, which returns a list of the `meta_value` for each post. But I'm not sure how to write this as the array I think I need for `$query->set("orderby", "meta_value");` to give me the desired outcome?

```
global $wpdb;
    $table_name = "xyz_custom_table";
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
      echo $retrieved_data->xyz_custom_meta;
    }
```

Comment: You need to ask this in a Pods community or via their support, 3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic here, this is not a place to get help with the Pods product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any custom tables in your database, you can override the SQL that WP_Query ends up using.

For this use case, I'd suggest not using WP_Query's arguments and building your own function to do this instead as it could simplify the logic and complexity.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'my_custom_wp_query_posts_clauses', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Custom WP_Query clauses to allow joining custom tables.
 *
 * @param array    $clauses The post clauses.
 * @param WP_Query $query   The WP_Query object.
 *
 * @return array The filtered post clauses.
 */
function my_custom_wp_query_posts_clauses( array $clauses, WP_Query $query ): array {
    // Only override for the main query that is not on a feed/admin page and is on the post type archive.
    if (
        ! $query->is_main_query()
        || $query->is_feed()
        || is_admin()
        || ! $query->is_post_type_archive( 'xyz_cpt' )
    ) {
        return $clauses;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    // Add the custom join with the wp_pods_PODNAME table.
    $clauses['join'] .= "
        LEFT JOIN `{$wpdb->prefix}pods_xyz_cpt` AS `pods_table`
            ON `pods_table`.`id` = `{$wpdb->posts}`.`ID`
    ";

    // Set our custom orderby.
    $orderby = '`pods_table`.`your_field_name`';

    // If the orderby is not already set then add ours to the front, otherwise set the orderby to ours.
    if ( ! empty( $clauses['orderby'] ) ) {
        $clauses['orderby'] = $orderby . ', ' . $clauses['orderby'];
    } else {
        $clauses['orderby'] = $orderby;
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

If you instead needed to add custom WHERE stuff, you'd just add whatever SQL you wanted to `$clauses['where']` too.

Answer (score 0):

**`WP_Query` isn't able to use 3rd party tables, and can't be added via `pre_get_posts`.**

You would need to rely on the SQL filters to adjust the raw SQL to match the custom tables being used.

Pods may provide a Pods specific solution, but if Pods is giving you the option to move things to another table then you will need a Pods specific answer that only works for Pods to solve your problem. *You need to ask Pods support or in a Pods community. Pods/3rd party plugin dev support questions are off-topic here*

Comment: I don't think this is a pods-specific question, they are using Pods but anyone who wants to interact with WP_Query orderby/etc with custom tables in general can do this with some extra PHP (posted in my answer). Pods is just what they're using to manage their custom tables, but the answer is a great generic example of how to do this for any custom tables.

Comment: @ScottKingsleyClark that's why I wrote an answer rather than outright closing it, but would it be possible to write your answer with zero knowledge of Pods? If not then the question is offtopic.